# Rails Edit User Path Not Working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, routes

I have made a rails project with authentication being devise. I am having an issue though with getting to the edit users page.

What happens is when I manually go to `/users/1/edit` I can see the edit page. Though I cannot seem to figure out the route to put in my code. When I look at the routes it looks like all I have to do is `edit_user_path`. Though this brings me to `/user/1/edit`. Which is incorrect and does not work. I have tried to do `edit_users_path` which just fails.

This is my routes file

```
devise_for :users
resources :users, :only => [:show, :edit, :update ]
resources :users, :controller => "users"
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Paste the code where you have used it

Comment: @RSB `<%= link_to "Edit Info", edit_user_path %>` this is the call I try to make when they click on Edit Info

Comment: Were you able to get this to update your (what I'm assuming) profile page? I'm having a routing conflict with POST. Wondering what you have in your project.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you have missed passing user `object` or `id` with the path, use this instead

```
edit_user_path(user.id)
```

where `user` is the object. You can also pass `object`

```
edit_user_path(user)
```

Comment: Awesome! Thanks so much, I will accept this once it lets me

Answer (score 2):

To add to RSB answer.. I had the same issue:

```
edit_user_path(current_user)
```

fixed it.